# changing OWNERSHIP of a file copied to device

Tags: android

When I copy a file from assets to the device, it copies just fine. The only problem is ownership. The file is ending up with the owner being '**app_59**', and I need it to be '**system**'. When I `adb push` a file, it goes as 'system'. I tried `chown`, I tried `chmod 0777` the file, I just cannot seem to do it! Can anyone help :(

Comment: Maybe you can get the system to come take it from you somehow? Why do you need the file to be owned by system?

Comment: it needs to be run by system.

Answer (score 1):

An application can't write something as the system user.  That would be a serious violation of security.  Also production devices do not provide root access from the shell, so it is not possible to push something to the device as anything besides the shell user; I assume you are doing your push on to the emulator, which is a very different environment in this regard (shell can run as root), so not applicable to a real device.

Comment: no im testing on a device. there is no way whatsoever ever ever ever to do this? i just need to run one file once as system ... rrrgh

Comment: Sorry, no, that would be a tremendous security hole (especially your later clarification that you want it to be "run as system").